# Using Protected Component for "Secret Protection" with Unlocked Packages

Tags: security, customsetting, custom-metadata, unlocked-package

How do "Protected Components" (Custom Settings or Custom Metadata) function when installed from an [Unlocked Package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp.htm).  I was hoping that I would be able to use as "Protected (Managed)" to store "secrets" as [described in this trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/secure-secret-storage/learn-about-platform-secret-protection).